# Style typing errors in Typescript/React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styles

I am new to TypeScript and am porting a reactjs project. A few errors popped up with the styles, including the tableLayout, borderCollapse and userSelect properties.

Doing some Googling yielded an explanation for this type of error:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18744
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11465

and I was able to get rid of the errors with type coercion eg

`const someStyle = {
    ...
    userSelect: 'none' as 'none',
    ...
}`

It seems @types/react uses frenic/CSSType. Do these errors represent omissions in their typed styles, or am I doing something wrong? Should they be reported there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, it's not a result of either omissions nor something you've done. You could even say it's because the types are *too* specific, but really this is a limitation of typescript itself.

As the [first issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18744) mentions, it's an issue with what type is given to an object literal when it's declared (specifically, that object fields holding a string are given the type `string` and not their literal type).

This isn't something that's likely to ever change, given that there is already a not-too-awful workaround (the type cast you demonstrate). Moreover, from that issue (near the bottom):

> we have no plans on changing the design at this point. we already had
>   multiple iterations on how literal types are inferred and the current
>   design seems to be the best compromise we can reach.

So ultimately, this is something we have to live with. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The reason I think they may be omissions is that the vast majority of cases *do* work. There is no problem with verticalAlign: 'top' or backgroundColor: 'inherit' etc, so there must be some magic making those cases work that has not been applied to these few?

Comment: [Here's the type](https://github.com/frenic/csstype/blob/master/index.d.ts#L17178) for `verticalAlign`. Note the `| string` at the end, which allows any string. So really that type is too broad, even though it does fix the issue you're seeing. The author could include that same `| string` on the definitions for other properties (such as `userSelect`), but that would make it too permissible, and would allow typos like `userSelect: "nonee"` to pass type checking. Both have drawbacks and benefits, so I don't think it's an omission per se. But I see what you mean, and it's possible it was.

Comment: OK, thanks. This is unsatisfactory though, either way - having the catch-all '| string' removes the benefit of typing these properties in the first place, but nobody is going to coerce every value to a literal when the property is defined as a union. Maybe a function to replace selected string property values with literals should be provided by CSSType? Or a typescript literal-string shorthand? Preprocessing? Something!

Comment: I guess these properties should first be defined as union of literal const values, which are exported, so you could eg go
userSelect: StyleProps.none, or similar.